# Overlapping of array objects in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I am getting an array in request body like :

```
[
   {
     "month": "JUL",
     "year": "2018"
   },
   {
     "month": "JAN",
     "year": "2018"
   },
   {
     "month": "MAR",
     "year": "2018"
   }
 ]
```

This input has two parameters (`month:enum` and `year:string`).

I need to loop through this array and call the chaincode and finally send the response . I have done the following :

```
for (var i = 0; i < req.body.length; i++) {
  var month = req.body[i].month;
  var year = req.body[i].year;
  var monthYear = month + year;
  key = monthYear + "_new";
  console.log("Key is ", key);
  var request = {
    //targets: let default to the peer assigned to the client
    chaincodeId: 'abc',
    fcn: 'getTransactionsByKey',
    args: [key]

    //Calling chaincode smartcontract
    return channel.queryByChaincode(request);
  }
```

but the response is coming correct if I pass only one input parameter . If I pass two values in input , the 2nd value result overrides the first one . Any help on how can I get response for all the list of inputs with the overlapping part.

Also , I need to sort the input values before calling the chaincode , like if I get Feb Mar Jan in the input , I should sort it as Jan Feb Mar and then run the for loop.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you Post what Output you getting exactly and what output you want ? @Aditi

Comment: Thanks for your reply Prashant . I am getting the output as :

Comment: Thanks for your reply Prashant . I am getting the output as :
  [
    {
        "from_userId": "abc",
        "to_userId": "def",
        "transaction_date": "Tue Jul 31 2018 19:40:48 GMT+0530 (IST)",

    }
] 
whereas I want : 
 [
    {
        "from_userId": "abc",
        "to_userId": "def",
        "transaction_date": "Tue Jul 31 2018 19:40:48 GMT+0530 (IST)",

    },
     {
        "from_userId": "abc2",
        "to_userId": "def2",
        "transaction_date": "Tue Jan 1 2018 19:40:48 GMT+0530 (IST)",
    }
]

Comment: @Aditi   `channel.queryByChaincode(request)` function is async function?

Comment: @Rahul - yes its an async function

Comment: @Aditi is it returning promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code May be it's work for you

```
var request=[];
 for(var i=0; i<req.body.length; i++) {
                    var month =req.body[i].month;
                    var year = req.body[i].year;
                    var monthYear = month + year;
    key = monthYear + "_new";
        console.log("Key is ", key);
             request.push( {
            //targets: let default to the peer assigned to the client
             chaincodeId: 'abc',
             fcn: 'getTransactionsByKey',
             args: key
             });

//Calling chaincode smartcontract
}
  console.log(request);
 return channel.queryByChaincode(request);
```

Output:

```
[ { chaincodeId: 'abc',
    fcn: 'getTransactionsByKey',
    args: 'JAN2018_new' },
  { chaincodeId: 'abc',
    fcn: 'getTransactionsByKey',
    args: 'JUL2018_new' },
  { chaincodeId: 'abc',
    fcn: 'getTransactionsByKey',
    args: 'MAR2018_new' } ]
```

Comment: I am looking for something which would concatenate my array responses from chaincode . Something like Array.prototype.push.apply () , but not sure how to use it . Any help on this please

Comment: My code already concat your array check the updated code.@Aditi

Answer (score 0):

Create Array of all request object and pass that to queryByChaincode.

```
var requests = req.body.map((body) => {
    return {
        chaincodeId: 'abc',
        fcn: 'getTransactionsByKey',
        args: [`${body.month}${body.year}_new`]
    };
});
return channel.queryByChaincode(requests);
```